# Can I debug (set breakpoints) in TypeScript files in a VS 2012 Windows Store app?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-store-apps, typescript

I have a Visual Studio 2012 Windows Store (Win 8) app that I have setup to use TypeScript files to generate the JavaScript.  When I try to set a breakpoint in the TypeScript files, Visual Studio gives me this message:

> This breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been
>   loaded for this document.

Is it possible to set breakpoints in *.ts files in a Windows Store project in VS 2012?

If so, how does the project have to be configured to do so?

Comment: I don't have that specific setup anymore so I can't try it. My recollection was that it didn't always work. I used `debugger;` statements a lot. :/  (You could also try deleting/uninstalling the application you're building to see if it's a caching issue).